# Google shop certified badge integration on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have tried to integrate google shop certified on my wordpress website. I have put the given code just before the  tag in the themes footer.php file and also put the shopping account currently. But whenever I tried to test the code integration google replied that no code found. I have inspect those pages and found those codes.Is there any successful way to integrate the google shopping certified badge?

Thanks in Advance
Sahariar

Answer (score 0):

If you use a caching plugin be sure to flush the cache, also if your server uses a caching library such as varnish or cloudflare be sure to flush them as well.